# What inline elements can be contained within <input> tag?

Tags: html, validation

What are the valid html elements, that can be contained with in a `<input>` tag? Haven't found proper documentation regarding this which is why I had to raise the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML specification is here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

The [input element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) section says:

> Content model: Empty.

There are no valid HTML elements allowed inside an `<input>`.

It also says:

> Tag omission in text/html: **No end tag**

… which makes it impossible to place an element inside it with HTML since to do that you must put the child element between the start tag and the end tag.

---

See also [Mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> Permitted content:    **None, it is an empty element.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't place any element inside an input. An input does not contain any HTML.

Comment: Could you provide documentation regarding this?

Comment: [_“**Permitted content:** None, it is an empty element.”_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: Xufux gave you the documentation ^^